Meaning of “G” in aviation
The Singapore Ministry of Transport just published the preliminary report for SQ flight 321 yesterday (https://www.mot.gov.sg/news/details/transport-safety-investigation-bureau-preliminary-investigation-findings-of-incident-involving-sq321).
My question is about statement 3(a). It stated that -

The Gravitational force (G), recorded as vertical accelerations, fluctuated between positive (+ve) 0.44G and +ve 1.57G for a period of about 19 sec. (This would have caused the flight to begin to experience slight vibration)

Not an aviation expert here but in more layman understanding, vertically an aircraft could only be affected by either gravitational force or lift. And gravitational force, according to Newton’s law of universal gravitation (or Einstein’s general relativity if you prefer), should not change as long as the mass of the aircraft and the Earth do not change.
So it confuses me so much when the statement wrote that “gravitational force changes” (and this is reported by many news outlets).
Again, I’m not an aviation expert so here is my question: what IS the meaning of G in aviation? Or is there anything wrong with my understanding? Thank you.

From review: Does this answer your question? What is a "rapid changes in gravitational force"

G is a dimensionless ratio based upon the acceleration of an object divided by the acceleration that same object experiences in an earth-normal gravity field.  This is equal to 9.81 m/s^2 or 32.2 ft/s^2.
A person standing on Earth is subject to an acceleration of 9.81 m/s^2 due to the force of gravity.  That person is said to be in a 9.81/9.81 = 1G.  A pilot flying a military fighter in a hard turn to the left may experience an acceleration as high as 100 m/s^2 towards the outside of the turn.  This works out to be 100/9.81 = 10.2 G.
G ‘forces’ are also equivalent to the aircraft load factor at any given time.  Load factor is the ratio of the lift force created by the wings divided by the weight of the aircraft.  A light airplane weighing 2500 pounds and whose wings produce 10,000 pounds of lift at a given time is also subject to 4 G, since the 10000 lbs of lift divided by the 2500 lb gross weight also equal to 4.  Consequently, the airplane experiences an acceleration in the direction of the lift vector equal to 4 * 9.81 m/s^2 = 39.24 m/s^2.
In the case cited above, the aircraft is subject to aerodynamic loads, resulting in an acceleration upon the airframe which varied between +4.32 m/s^2 and -15.40 m/s^2, resulting in the cited +0.44/-1.57 G range.  The Singapore Ministry of Transport is not quite accurate in calling Gs The gravitational force.   As you correctly pointed out the gravitational force across the Earth is, for all intents and purposes here, constant.  But the loads and accelerations experienced by a person in flight from a certain reference point will vary due to the net forces acting upon their body.

When we use the term g's, we don't mean that gravity is actually changing.  Instead, we're normalizing the acceleration we feel by something we're familiar with -- i.e. the acceleration due to gravity.
When we're sitting statically in a chair, we feel 1g.  Gravity is pulling us down, the chair is pushing back up, we aren't accelerating either way.  This is normal.
Think about a time when you've felt significant vertical acceleration.  When a car or a roller coaster crests the top of a hill -- or rounds the bottom of a valley.  Or when a high speed elevator starts to drop from the top floor, or comes to a stop at the bottom.
In these situations, you feel either lighter or heavier.  Gravity is still pulling down the same, but the forces on you are not in equilibrium.  Either the chair or the floor below you is pushing up harder than your weight -- or it is pushing up less.  Because the forces are not in equilibrium, you are accelerating.  Or alternatively, because the chair (and car, roller coaster, or elevator around it) are accelerating, there is an imbalance of forces.
If you were in total free-fall (say you had jumped off a high dive, bungee jumping, or went sky diving) before the air resistance (or rubber band) slows you down, there are no forces pushing back up and you accelerate at the full acceleration due to gravity 9.8 $m/s^2$.  We call this feeling zero g's.  It is what astronauts feel all the time.
In fact, gravity is still present for astronauts in space.  Gravity is what keeps the spacecraft in orbit.  The spacecraft is in a freefall -- like the moment you step off a bungee jump.  But it is also moving 'around' the earth at a fast enough rate to exactly counter act the freefall.  They move forward with great speed and gravity pulls them inward to the earth -- together they maintain a circular path called an orbit.  This state of constant freefall means they feel weightless (zero g's) the whole time.
Back to our people in an airplane.  Instead of a nice smooth ride, they are basically riding a rough roller coaster with bumps up and down.  When they reach the peaks and must accelerate down, they feel less than one g like when the elevator starts to go down.  When they reach a valley and must accelerate back up, they feel more than one g like the roller coaster curving back up.
This oscillation can happen slow or fast -- slow and it might only feel like rocking of waves.  Fast and it will feel like driving on a rough dirt road with no suspension.
